# Shell text to python string

Tags: python, shell, documentation

I'm writing a little python utility to help move our shell `-help` documentation to searchable webpages, but I hit a weird block :

```
output = subprocess.Popen([sys.argv[1], '--help'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
output = output.split('\n')
print output[4]
#NAME
for l in output[4]:
    print l
#N
#A
#
#A
#M
#
#M
#E
#
#E

#or when written, n?na?am?me?e
```

It does this for any `heading/subheading` in the documentation, which makes it near unusable.

Any tips on getting correct formatting? Where did I screw up?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get for `print repr(output[4])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation contains overstruck characters done in the ancient line-printer way: print each character, followed by a backspace (`\b` aka `\x08`), followed by the same character again. So "NAME" becomes `"N\bNA\bAM\bME\bE"`. If you can convince the program *not* to output that way, it would be the best; otherwise, you can clean it up with something like `output = re.sub(r'\x08.', '', output)`

Answer (score 1):

A common way to mark a character as bold in a terminal is to print the character, followed by a backspace characters, followed by the character itself again (just like you would do it on a mechanical typewriter).  Terminal emulators like `xterm` detect such sequences and turn them into bold characters.  Programs shouldn't be printing such sequences if stdout is not a terminal, but if your tool does, you will have to clean up the mess yourself.

Comment: It was also sometimes used to perform underlining by printing the character, then by a backspace, then the underscore character.